Tkinter progress bar works on Linux but not on Windows
I wrote the following basic code sample that creates a main window with a button. When the button is pressed a second window with a progress bar should appear and stay open until the progress is complete. This works fine on Linux but on Windows the second window appears blank with no progress bar. Given that this will be part of an application that runs on Windows. What should I do? Is this a bug or what's going on?
I'm using python 3.12.5 on both Linux and Windows 11 (build 22631).
The code
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time


def cpw():
    tasks = 5
    increment = 100 / tasks

    pw = tk.Toplevel()
    pw.title("Progress Window")
    pw.geometry("300x135")
    pb = ttk.Progressbar(
        pw,
        name="pb",
        orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
        length=200,
        mode="determinate",
    )
    pb.pack()

    i = 0
    while i < tasks:
        i += 1
        pb["value"] += increment
        pb.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)

    pw.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.geometry("150x100")

tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=cpw).pack()

root.mainloop()


Don't use time.sleep with tkinter. Use something like this instead.

@TheLizzard The time.sleep(1) call is just for ilustrative purposes.

Yeah, it illustrates what to prevent: blocking code in UIs. Blocking code should be run concurrently, for example in a separate thread.

.update_idletasks() may not handle pending creation of widget.  Try adding pb.update() after pb.pack().

Thanks @acw1668 pb.update() after pb.pack() solved it.

@acw1668 maybe you could add a proper answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Thanks to @acw1668 who pointed out in the comments that .update_idletasks() may not handle pending creation of widgets. Adding pb.update() or also pb.wait_visibility(pw) before pb.pack() will ensure the creation and visibility of the progress window and bar.
Documentation here

As stated in comments, your use of the time module in tkinter is causing the problem.
Implementing tkinter after requires a different approach to your time delay method.
Replace
    i = 0
    while i < tasks:
        i += 1
        pb["value"] += increment
        pb.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)

    pw.destroy()

with this code snippet.
    def looper(i):
        if i < tasks:
            pb["value"] += increment
            pw.after(1000, looper, i+1)
        else:
            pw.destroy()

    pw.after(1000, looper, 0)


Thanks @Derek. Even though I don't actually want any delay, I was just using time.sleep(1) to demonstrate that a long-running process will be in place of the time.sleep(1). But yeah, pw.after() does make the bar appear. I think, as @acw1668 pointed out in the comments below my post, .update_idletasks() may not handle the pending creation of widgets, so one can either use pw.after(1000, looper, 0) or pb.update() after pb.pack() to ensure the creation of the progress bar.
